# What is the replacement of disableMaskedInput in version 6 of MUI X DatePicker?

Tags: material-ui

I'm upgrading MUI X DatePicker from version 5 to version 6.

We used to remove the mask when clicking on the text field.

This was done using the prop disableMaskedInput.

Problem : It seems the prop disableMaskedInput doesn't exist anymore.

Question : How am I supposed to replace it now ?

Here is the version I had of the datePicker :

```html
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterLuxon} adapterLocale={language}>
  <DatePicker
    disablePast
    disableMaskedInput
    components={{
      OpenPickerIcon: () => <IconCalendar size={20} color={"light-gray"} />,
    }}
    value={date}
    onChange={(date: DateTime) => setDate(date)}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        sx={{
          // Some design stuff
        }}
        inputProps={{
          ...params.inputProps,
          placeholder: "This is a custom placeholder",
       }}
     />
    )}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

Here's the modification I made sofar :

```html
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterLuxon} adapterLocale={language}>
  <DatePicker
    disablePast
    <!-- disableMaskedInput : How am I supposed to replace this ? -->
    slots={{
      openPickerIcon: () => <IconCalendar size={20} color={TakeTurnsColors.grayButton} />,
    }}
    value={date}
    onChange={(date: DateTime) => setDate(date)}
    slotProps={{
      textField: {
        sx: {
          // Some design stuff
        },
      inputProps: {
        placeholder: t("deadlinePlaceholder"),
      },
    }}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

I searched on github, and in the documentation of MUI X, and can't find reference about it.

TLDR : disableMaskedInput doesn't exist anymore on MUI X DatePicker version 6. What is the replacement ?